# How to access all the direct children of a div in tailwindcss?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have this html:

```
<div class="section">
   <div class="header">header</div>
   <div class="content">
      <div>sub contents 1</div>              
      <div>sub contents 2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to access the direct children of div with class "section" which would be divs with class: "header" and "content".

I know with css we can do: `div.section > div`

But how to do this using **tailwindcss**?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

There are three options these days.

### Option 1 - Plugins

You could use these simple lines in `tailwind.config.js` to give you `child` and `child-hover` options.

```
plugins: [
    function ({ addVariant }) {
        addVariant('child', '& > *');
        addVariant('child-hover', '& > *:hover');
    }
],
```

Then use like this

```
<div class="child:text-gray-200 child-hover:text-blue-500">...</div>
```

Which will give every child a gray textcolor, and a blue one on hover.

See [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-variants) for more information on adding variants using a plugin

### Option 2 - Ad-hoc selectors

Since 4th of july 2022, Tailwind added an ad-hoc approach to target specific elements. You can now use the below without any need for plugins.

```
<div class="[&>*]:text-gray-200 [&>*:hover]:text-blue-500">...</div>
```

See the answer of @phum for more info!

### Option 3 - Native child selectors

Since 19th of december 2023, Tailwind added child selectors! You can now use the below.

```
<div class="*:text-gray-200 hover:*:text-blue-500">...</div>
```

See [here](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-4) for the release notes.

Comment: This was a lifesaver for me. If you're looking for an even more permissive version where the parent effects all children, you can utilize `& *` and `&:hover *` respectively. This came in handy for component development

Comment: How to achieve the same in browser using CDN? I tried doing `tailwind.config = { plugins: () => {...}}` but that is not working.

Comment: @SrikanthSharma Interesting; I did not know they had a CDN version. Looking at the documentation, it seems like they do actually support plugins in the CDN version (which would be a miracle in itself). Maybe you did not define plugins as an Array?

Comment: `:child` variant alone should suffice but `child:hover:...` becomes `:hover > *` and vise versa, which is weird since tailwind docs say that the variants are applied in the order they were given ... so `child-hover` is needed

Comment: @Sodj You'll have to do `hover:child:` instead and it should work 

Answer (score 333):

In tailwind 3.1, you can use arbitrary values to target child elements.

```
<div class="[&>*]:p-4">...</div>
<div class="[&>p]:mt-0 ">...</div>
```

https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-1#arbitrary-values-but-for-variants

As mentioned by @kca in the comments, space in the selectors need to be replaced by an underscore character in Tailwind classes. For example if you want to select all descendants, not just the direct children then you can use this:

```
<div class="[&_*]:p-4">...</div>
<div class="[&_p]:mt-0 ">...</div>
```

Comment: I would say that this should not be used at all. Why? Because if this is for example component as children you are changing styles of the component from different place that it have its own styles. It creates technical depth, it is hardly findable and I presume that this is not good practice at all.

Comment: I agree that if possible this solution should not be implemented, however, there are times when you can't access to style HTML directly(e.g. 3rd party script). It can be a pretty useful escape hatch when trying to style HTML you can’t directly change.

Comment: Note that spaces for selecting descendants need to be replaced by underscores, e.g. `'[&_svg]:stroke-white'` instead of `'[& svg]:stroke-white'`. See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants

Comment: @kca Consider adding this to the above answer. I was having trouble with exactly this. The answer should include your point.

Comment: https://play.tailwindcss.com/rq8YVDB3LG

Comment: Native child selectors are now also supported since 19th dec 2023 :-)

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? The link in this post does not work (anymore). Can't find anything on tailwinds website...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to access the direct children of div with selector, please use `@layer` directive. see below:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  div.section > div {
    @apply text-xl;
  }
}
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-base-styles

Comment: idk but this doesnt work for me `div.field_with_errors > label { @apply text-red-900; }`

Comment: note that the base layer should only contain the apps default styling of commonly used tags, and is not designed for specific use-case styling

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible and probably won't be implemented soon.

Instead, I recommend using this plugin:  https://github.com/benface/tailwindcss-children. Follow the README for further instructions.

#### Usage:

After you have installed the plugin and added it to your `tailwind.config.js`, you can access direct children by adding `children:{your_style}` to the parent class. If you for example would want to add `p-4` to `header` and `content`, your code would look like this:

```html
<div class="section children:p-4">
   <div class="header">header</div>
   <div class="content">
      <div>sub contents 1</div>              
      <div>sub contents 2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: This is deprecated and doesn't work with tailwind 3.0

Comment: There's a new library for Tailwind v3+: [tailwind-children](https://github.com/SamGoody/tailwind-children)

Comment: Can confirm, works for Tailwind 3+. Personally this is my preferred answer, since it allows us to mix existing variants along with the `child:` (and others) this one brings.

Answer (score 1):

This is tailwind v1&v2 version of Willem Mulder's.

only change is variant name `children` instead of `child`

```
 plugin(function({ addVariant, e }) {

  addVariant('children', ({ modifySelectors, separator }) => {
    modifySelectors(({ className }) => {
      const newClass = e(`children${separator}${className}`);
      return [
        `.${newClass} > *`,
        // `.${newClass}:hover `,
      ].join(",");
    });
  });

  addVariant('children-first', ({ modifySelectors, separator }) => {
    modifySelectors(({ className }) => {
      const newClass = e(`children-first${separator}${className}`);
      return [
        `.${newClass} > *:first-child`,
      ].join(",");
    });
  });

}),
```

add variants for padding

```
variants: {
    padding: ['responsive', 'children', 'children-hover', 'children-first', ],
   
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way that i found to write classes.
This can also work with things like hover,active,etc.
in svelte

```html
  <div class=` 
{ classer("[&>button:hover]","bg-slate-500 scale-110") } 
{ classer("[&>button]","bg-slate-400 w-full my-2 py-2 rounded") }
` >
```

Ts function like

```js
export function classer(selector:string, allclasses:string):string  {
  let classList = allclasses.split(" ")
  return classList.map((item) => selector+":" + item).join(" ")
}
```