# How to access all the children of a div in tailwindcss with hover event?

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a nav bar like this:

```
<nav class="space-x-4">
  <router-link to="/home" class="hover:text-gray-300 transition duration-300">Home</router-link>
  <router-link to="/form" class="hover:text-gray-300 transition duration-300">Form</router-link>
  <router-link to="/about" class="hover:text-gray-300 transition duration-300">About</router-link>
</nav>
```

But i'd like to avoid the class duplication so I tried the syntax mentionned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67119992/how-to-access-all-the-direct-children-of-a-div-in-tailwindcss):

```
<nav class="space-x-4 [&>router-link]:hover:text-gray-300 transition duration-300">
  <router-link to="/home">Home</router-link>
  <router-link to="/form">Form</router-link>
  <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
</nav>
```

It works well except that when I hover one element, it highlight all the elements.
It appear that grouping the class this way is also grouping the event handling ...

I've got exactly 1 hour experience on tailwind so sorry by advance if I missed this point on the docs but I didn't find anything about my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do exactly what you want to do with inline css and tailwind classes, you just need to modify your code slightly. Here's how:

```html
<nav class="space-x-4 hover:[&>a]:text-gray-300 transition duration-300">
  <router-link to="/home">Home</router-link>
  <router-link to="/form">Form</router-link>
  <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
</nav>
```

You can swap `[&>a]` for `[&>router-link]`, if that works for you.

Comment: oh ! Simply place the DOM ever trigger before the inheritance parameter ! I was so close ahah Thx for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Alright I just found my solution in the docs [right there](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-classes-with-apply).

HTML:

```
<nav class="space-x-4">
  <router-link to="/home" class="nav-btn">Home</router-link>
  <router-link to="/form" class="nav-btn">Form</router-link>
  <router-link to="/about" class="nav-btn">About</router-link>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .nav-btn {
    @apply hover:text-gray-300 transition duration-300
  }
}
```